# WP Plugin "Store Locator Plus" - "only_with_tag" not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I'm having an issue with a Wordpress plugin called "Store Locator Plus", where the feature "only_with_tag=[TAG]" does not actually filter the map by tags. I'm currently using a shortcode similar to: `[SLPLUS id=1 only_with_tag="michigan"]`, and I'm not seeing any change. Interestingly, a sister-feature is working just fine: `[SLPLUS id=1 only_with_category="michigan" ]`

All locations have been tagged accordingly, and while the sister feature works just fine for Categories, I also need these to support Tags. The documentation mentions code needing to be added to our map template, which seems to have no effect. We've tried the URL variable route, which is also not working as intended.

Has anybody else had this issue? Is it conflicting with another setting? The documentation has a lot of holes in it, and I'm just scratching my head trying to figure out how to make it work. Any help would be appreciated, just let me know what more information you need to make suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried reaching out to the plugin developer's support? That seems like the first place to try.

Comment: I haven't had very good luck with this plugin's developer. Some of the issues get resolved, but a lot of the feedback is "upgrade to the latest version". Once we confirm that I've done that, the feedback tends to fizzle out, or unrelated items are brought up which have no effect on the end result. I feel like this plugin works much better for smaller businesses, but my clients have much more specific needs, and now I'm kind of locked-in with this plugin, so it's too late to turn back... but I still can't do everything I should be able to. Very frustrating.

Comment: That's sort of the catch with third-party plugins. Since this is a very specific issue you are having - you're not likely to get much better help here vs. the developer - which is obviously not the answer you are looking for. Good luck!